# Understanding Bash Script argument expressions

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

With the help of a number of web searches, SO questions and answers, and trial-and-error I have written the following script to send attachments to an email.

```
attachments=""
subject=""

args=( "$@" )                   #   Copy arguments
recipient="${@: -1}"            #   Last argument
unset "args[${#args[@]}-1]"     #   Remove last argument

for i in "${args[@]}"; do       #   Remaining Arguments
    attachments="$attachments -a $i"
    subject="$subject $i"
done

eval "echo 'See Attached …' | mail -r 'Fred <fred@example.net>' $attachments -s \"Attached: $subject\" $recipient"
```

It works perfectly using something like

```
send.sh file1 file2 file3 recipient@example.com
```

I have omitted some of the refinements in the above code, such as error checking, but the whole thing works as planned.

I have no trouble with the process, and I have good programming skills. However I find that Bash scripting is like medieval Latin to me, and I an having a hard time understanding the four expressions which I have commented.

The idea is that I pop the last argument, which is supposed to be the recipient, and loop through the remaining arguments which will be attached files.

Can anybody detail the meanings of the expressions `$@`, `${@: -1}`, `${args[@]}`, and `args[${#args[@]}-1]`, and explain what the hash is doing in the last expression?

No doubt the script could stand some improvement, but I only trying to understand what is happening so far.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: How did you write the script if you don't actually understand what you wrote?

Comment: @Barmar I searched for things like popping the last argument and found enough examples there. I’m not saying I have no idea what I wrote, just that four commented expressions were copied and adapted without a detailed understanding of them.

Comment: They're all explained in the Bash Manual, whose link is in @KamilCuk's comment.

Comment: @Barmar Not really. For example the expression `$@` gets one mention, and doesn’t explain what `( "$@" )` is doing.

Comment: `$@` is in "Special Parameters", it contains all the arguments to the script. `()` is explained in the "Arrays" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in [bash manual shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and some in [bash special parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html). So:

---

> Can anybody detail the meanings of the expressions `$@`

From the manual, important parts:

> $@
>
> ($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. [...]
>
> if not within double quotes, these words are subject to word splitting. In contexts where word splitting is not performed, this expands to a single word with each positional parameter separated by a space. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, and word splitting is performed, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ...

So `"$@"` is equal to `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...` for each parameter passed. [Word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) is that thing that when a variable is not quoted, it splits argument on spaces, like: `a="arg1 arg2 arg3"; f $a` runs `f` with 3 arguments.

---

> ```
> ${@: -1}
> ```

From [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> ${parameter:offset}
>      ${parameter:offset:length}
>
> It expands to up to length characters of the value of parameter starting at the character specified by offset [...]
>
> If parameter is ‘@’, the result is *length* positional parameters beginning at *offset*. A negative *offset* is taken relative to one greater than the greatest positional parameter, so an *offset* of -1 evaluates to the last positional parameter.

So `${@: -1}` is the last positional argument passed to the script. The additional space is there because `${parameter:-word}` means something different.

---

> ```
> ${args[@]}
> ```

From [bash manual arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays):

> Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}. The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell’s filename expansion operators. If the subscript is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the word expands to all members of the array name.

`${args[@]}` is equal to `${args[1]} ${args[2]} ${args[3]}`. Note that without quotes word splitting is performed. In your code you have `for i in "${args[@]}"` - words are preserved.

---

> ```
> args[${#args[@]}-1]
> ```

From [bash manual shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ${#parameter}
>
> If parameter is an array name subscripted by ‘*’ or ‘@’, the value substituted is the number of elements in the array.

So `${#args[@]}` expands to the count of elements in an array. The count of elements `-1` is the index of last element. So `args[${#args[@]}-1]` is `args[<the index of last array element>]`. The `unset "args[${#args[@]}-1]"` is used to remove last array element.

---

> explain what the hash is doing in the last expression?

The hash is there to trigger proper variable expansion.

---

> what ( "$@" ) is doing.

From manual:

> Arrays are assigned to using compound assignments of the form
>
> name=(value1 value2 … )

The `var=("$@")` creates an array `var` with the copy of positional parameters properly expanded with words preserved.

Comment: “The hash is there to trigger proper variable expansion.” Is that right? The parameter expansion section suggests that it represents the count of argments.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is explained somewhere in the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html)

- `$@` in [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters)

> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. In contexts where word splitting is performed, this expands each positional parameter to a separate word; if not within double quotes, these words are subject to word splitting.

- `${@: -1}` in [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

> `${parameter:offset}`
>   `${parameter:offset:length}`
>   ... If *parameter* is ‘@’, the result is *length* positional parameters beginning at *offset*. A negative *offset* is taken relative to one greater than the greatest positional parameter, so an *offset* of -1 evaluates to the last positional parameter.

- `${args[@]}` in [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays)

> Any element of an array may be referenced using `${name[subscript]}`. The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell’s filename expansion operators. If the *subscript* is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the word expands to all members of the array name.

- `args[${#args[@]}-1]` also in Arrays:

> `${#name[subscript]}` expands to the length of `${name[subscript]}`. If *subscript* is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the expansion is the number of elements in the array.